# Screen recording using RecordRTC - Unable to record video sounds playing on screen or through speaker

Tags: javascript, webrtc, recordrtc

I am trying to record screen with videos playing on screen + microphone of user.

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4z447wpn/5/

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Screen recording using RecordRTC</title>
<style>
    html, body{
        margin: 0!important;
        padding: 0!important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<video controls autoplay height="600" width="800" style="float: left; margin-top: 20px"></video>

<iframe width="420" height="315"  style="float: right; margin-top: 20px"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Zr2jjg1X-U">
</iframe> 

<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.WebRTC-Experiment.com/getScreenId.js"></script>
<script>
function captureScreen(cb) {
    getScreenId(function (error, sourceId, screen_constraints) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(screen_constraints).then(cb).catch(function(error) {
          console.error('getScreenId error', error);
          alert('Failed to capture your screen. Please check browser console logs for further information.');
        });
    });
}
function captureAudio(cb) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}).then(cb);
}
function keepStreamActive(stream) {
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.muted = true;
    setSrcObject(stream, video);
    video.style.display = 'none';
    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(video);
}

captureScreen(function(screen) {
    keepStreamActive(screen);

    captureAudio(function(mic) {
        keepStreamActive(mic);

        screen.width = window.screen.width;
        screen.height = window.screen.height;
        screen.fullcanvas = true;

        var recorder = RecordRTC([screen, mic], {
            type: 'video',
            mimeType: 'video/webm',
            previewStream: function(s) {
                document.querySelector('video').muted = true;
                setSrcObject(s, document.querySelector('video'));
            }
        });

        //Start recording
        recorder.startRecording();

        //Stop recording after specific seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
            recorder.stopRecording(function() {
                var blob = recorder.getBlob();
                document.querySelector('video').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                document.querySelector('video').muted = false;
                screen.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
                screen.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
                mic.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
                mic.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
            });
        }, 20 * 1000);

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notes:**

(1) Play iframe video(loaded on right-side) quickly after you allow access of browser screen and microphone, so it will start recording everything and it will auto stop after 20 seconds and will play recorded video. Pause right-side video to listen recorded sound.

(2) Chrome user needs to install extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capturing/ajhifddimkapgcifgcodmmfdlknahffk

**Problems I face:**

(1) It is not recording sounds playing in videos on screen. Though it captures full screen with microphone of user.

(2) If I select current screen as screen capture window, it shows same screen in loop.

See problems in image : [image: recordRTC-screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your demo works on localhost or on a non-iframe based HTTPs website after passing "**second**" parameter over `getScreenId` e.g.

```
getScreenId(callback, true);
```

Where second argument i.e. boolean `true` **enabled the speakers**.

Note: If still doesn't works then test on incognito to ignore/bypass cache.

Note2: Test on localhost or non-iframe HTTPs website i.e. on your own domain instead of jsfiddle.

---

*Updated the answer on Tuesday May 08 2018*

Please try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Screen recording using RecordRTC</title>
    <style>
        html, body{
            margin: 0!important;
            padding: 0!important;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="stoprecording">STOP RECORDING</button>

    <video id="preview-screen" controls autoplay height="600" width="800" style="float: left; margin-top: 20px"></video>

    <video width="420" height="315" controls="" autoplay="" loop="" style="float: right; margin-top: 20px" onloadedmetadata="typeof OnLoadedMetaData === 'function' ? OnLoadedMetaData() : setTimeout(function() {OnLoadedMetaData();}, 3000);">
        <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.WebRTC-Experiment.com/getScreenId.js"></script>
    <script>
    function captureScreen(cb) {
        getScreenId(function (error, sourceId, screen_constraints) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(screen_constraints).then(cb).catch(function(error) {
              console.error('getScreenId error', error);
              alert('Failed to capture your screen. Please check browser console logs for further information.');
            });
        }, true);
    }
    function captureAudio(cb) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}).then(cb);
    }
    function keepStreamActive(stream) {
        var video = document.createElement('video');
        video.muted = true;
        setSrcObject(stream, video);
        video.style.display = 'none';
        (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(video);
    }

    var recorder = '';
    var screenRec = '';
    var micRec = '';

    function OnLoadedMetaData (){
        captureScreen(function(screen) {
            keepStreamActive(screen);

            captureAudio(function(mic) {
                keepStreamActive(mic);

                screen.width = window.screen.width;
                screen.height = window.screen.height;
                screen.fullcanvas = true;

                recorder = RecordRTC([screen, mic], {
                    type: 'video',
                    mimeType: 'video/webm',
                    previewStream: function(s) {
                        document.querySelector('#preview-screen').muted = true;
                        setSrcObject(s, document.querySelector('#preview-screen'));
                    }
                });

                screenRec = screen;
                micRec = mic;

                //Start recording
                recorder.startRecording();

            });

            addStreamStopListener(screen, function() {
                btnStopRecording.click();
            });
        });
    }

    var btnStopRecording = document.getElementById('stoprecording');
    btnStopRecording.onclick = function() {
        this.disabled = true;

        recorder.stopRecording(function() {
            var blob = recorder.getBlob();

            document.querySelector('#preview-screen').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            document.querySelector('#preview-screen').muted = false;

            screenRec.getTracks().concat(micRec.getTracks()).forEach(function(track) {
                track.stop();
            });
        });
    };

    function addStreamStopListener(stream, callback) {
        var streamEndedEvent = 'ended';
        if ('oninactive' in stream) {
            streamEndedEvent = 'inactive';
        }
        stream.addEventListener(streamEndedEvent, function() {
            callback();
            callback = function() {};
        }, false);
        stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            track.addEventListener(streamEndedEvent, function() {
                callback();
                callback = function() {};
            }, false);
        });
        stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            track.addEventListener(streamEndedEvent, function() {
                callback();
                callback = function() {};
            }, false);
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated parameters in getScreenId(callback, true)

Tested in localhost with https and non-iframe(it means with video element with mp4 video playing as source) and in private browsing/incognito mode in browsers. But it doesn't recording sounds other than mic.

Comment: Please set autoplay=true or similar flag for youtube video. On my side, it recorded both youtube audio, microphone and full-screen into a single WebM. Add Stop-Recording button instead of automatically stopping the video or otherwise click "stop screen sharing" blue button to exit the screen capturing.

Comment: I tried auto-play, stopping screen-share and with stop button but nothing worked. Can you please see code here if you find any issue with code: https://gist.github.com/hardiktailored/28303f600548e2ccfa7300a65e28689f

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.